# return count on nested documents in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to return the total conversation count for each of the `agentid` and I'm not able to get it.

Here is the situation. I have 2 supports from 2 agents. Each of the support has 3 and 5 conversations respectively. Right now, it returns a count of 1 instead of 3 or 5 conversations. I'm not sure what am I missing and I greatly appreciate any helps and many thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

MongoDB schema

```
const SupportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  agentid:{ type: ObjectID, ref: "Agent" },
  supporttype:{type:ObjectID,ref:"SupportType"},
  supportnumber:{type:Number},
  conversationtracking:[{
    agentid:{ type: ObjectID, ref: "Agent" },
    conversationtext:{type:String},
    conversationstage:{type:ObjectID,ref:"Stages"},
    conversationdate:{type:Date, default: Date.now}
  }],
  supportdate: {
    type:Date,
    default: Date.now 
  },
},
{ timestamps: true });
```

Trying to return to conversation count

```
const totalConversation = await Support.countDocuments({
  "conversationtracking.agentid": { 
    "$eq": agentid._id 
   }
})
.populate("conversationtracking.conversationstage", "stagename")
```

This is the sample data:

```
_id:609bc87890b1690154599098
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
supporttype:609a44016cab302ab051a154
supportnumber:3500
conversationtracking:Array
0:Object
_id:60af1f2946c5c029d42e74ab
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
conversationtext:"We collect anonymous data from every visitor of the Website to monitor..."
conversationstage:609a2ce785e24c2bfc7d9412
conversationdate:2021-05-21T04:25:00.000+00:00
1:Object
_id:60af1f1b46c5c029d42e74aa
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
conversationtext:"At design, we use the "Privacy by Design" approach. This means that we ..."
conversationstage:609a2cda85e24c2bfc7d9411
conversationdate:2021-05-19T04:24:42.000+00:00
2:Object
_id:60af1f0946c5c029d42e74a9
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
conversationtext:"The following Terms of Use govern your use and access of the Website (..."
conversationstage:609a2ca7b458572498a0330e
conversationdate:2021-05-17T04:24:31.000+00:00
createdAt:2021-05-12T12:22:16.854+00:00
updatedAt:2021-05-27T04:25:13.975+00:00
__v:0

_id:609bc727362e4c2024866945
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
supporttype:609a44016cab302ab051a154
supportnumber:3500
conversationtracking:Array
0:Object
_id:609b9c9873801c04e4252be4
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
conversationtext:"We collect anonymous data from every visitor of the Website to monitor..."
conversationstage:609a2ce785e24c2bfc7d9412
conversationdate:2021-05-21T04:25:00.000+00:00
1:Object
_id:60af1f6746c5c029d42e74ad
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
conversationtext:"At Eezee, we use the "Privacy by Design" approach. This means that we ..."
conversationstage:609a2cda85e24c2bfc7d9411
conversationdate:2021-05-19T04:24:42.000+00:00
2:Object
_id:60af1f4d46c5c029d42e74ac
agentid:6097f55c3946ec2974110929
conversationtext:"The following Terms of Use govern your use and access of the Website (..."
conversationstage:609a2ca7b458572498a0330e
conversationdate:2021-05-17T04:24:31.000+00:00
createdAt:2021-05-12T12:22:16.854+00:00
updatedAt:2021-05-27T04:25:13.975+00:00
__v:0
```

Based on this sample data, I'm getting 2 support counts and not 6 conversations count. How do I return 6 conversations count? Thanks

Comment: can you show some example documents and expected results based on that documents?

Comment: hi turivishal, I have edited the question to include the sample data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to count subelements by `countDocuments` function, you can try aggregation query,

- `$match` your conditions
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `conversationtracking` array and match `agentId`
- `$size` to get total elements in above filtered result
- `$group` by null and get the total count

```
const totalConversation = await Support.aggregate([
  { $match: { "conversationtracking.agentid": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(agentid._id) } },
  {
    $project: {
      count: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$conversationtracking",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.agentid", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(agentid._id)] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: { $sum: "$count" }
    }
  }
]);

console.log(totalConversation[0].count);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oO5RRUkOC6b)